# getting FileNotFound Exception when viewing a page that uses my custom facelet-taglib

Tags: jsf, richfaces, taglib

### Here is my context :

- I'm using Netbeans as an IDE
- richfaces 4 in my test webapp.
- glassfish 3.1.2

### Here is my detailed problem :

- I have a menu bar that I want to be able to reuse in several other pages.
- I believe this is what facelet-taglibs are for so I want to create one.

### Here is what I did :

- created the file containing my menu :
  menu.xhtml

> ```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>       xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
>       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
>     <h:body>
>         <ui:composition id="PAC-MENU">
>             <rich:toolbar width="50%">
>                 <rich:dropDownMenu>
>                 <f:facet name="label"> 
>                     <h:panelGroup>
>                         <h:graphicImage value="./images/icons/create_doc.gif" styleClass="pic"/>
>                         <h:outputText value="Declaration"/>
>                     </h:panelGroup>
>                 </f:facet>
>
>                 <rich:menuItem label="Upload" icon="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/icons/create_doc.gif" action="/pages/uploadDeclarationBatch"/>
>                 </rich:dropDownMenu>
>                 <rich:toolbarGroup location="right">
>                     <rich:dropDownMenu label="Profile" direction="bottomLeft" jointPoint="bottomRight">
>                         <rich:menuItem label="Update" action="/pages/updateProfile"/>
>                         <rich:menuItem label="Change password" action="/pages/changePassword"/>
>                     </rich:dropDownMenu>
>                 </rich:toolbarGroup>
>             </rich:toolbar>
>         </ui:composition>
>     </h:body>
> </html>
> ```

- created the taglib file :
  pac-taglibs.xhtml

  > ```
  > <?xml version='1.0'?>
  > <!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
  >   "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
  >   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
  >
  > <facelet-taglib version="2.0">
  >     <namespace>http://www.myproduct.com/jsf</namespace>
  >     <tag>
  >         <tag-name>pac-menu</tag-name> 
  >         <source>/resources/tags/menu.xhtml</source>
  >     </tag>
  > </facelet-taglib>
  > ```
- Modified the web.xml y adding this :
  web.xml

  > ```
  > <context-param>
  >      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name> 
  >      <param-value>/resources/taglibs/pac-taglibs.xhtml</param-value>
  > </context-param>
  > ```
- referenced my taglib in my page and use the tag like this :
  home.xhtml

  > ```
  > <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  > <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  > <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  >       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  >       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  >       xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  >       xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  >       xmlns:a3c="http://www.myproduct.com/jsf">
  >     <h:head>
  >         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ref="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/styles.css"/>
  >         <title>My Product V1.0 Beta</title>
  >     </h:head>
  >     <h:body styleClass="backGroundimage">
  >         <center>
  >             <h:form>
  >                 <h:outputText id="outtxt" styleClass="h1" value="Welcome ${pAC_USER.name}"/><BR/><BR/>
  >                 <a3c:pac-menu/>
  >             </h:form>
  >         </center>
  >     </h:body>
  > </html>
  > ```
- here is the directory structure :

> ```
> WebContent
>    |
>    ---> META-INF
>    |
>    ---> WEB-INF
>    |
>    ---> resources
>    |      |
>    |      ---> css
>    |      |
>    |      ---> taglibs
>    |      |      |
>    |      |      ---> pac-taglibs.xhtml
>    |      |      
>    |      ---> tags
>    |      |      |
>    |      |      ---> menu.xhtml
>    |     
>    ---> index.xhtml
> ```

and each time I try to access my page I've got this error message :

> ```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException
>   at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:403)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache._getLastModified(DefaultFaceletCache.java:172)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.access$000(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:82)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:78)
>   at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:121)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:256)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:366)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:326)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:142)
>   at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
>   at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>   at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
>   at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>   at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
>   at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>   at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
>   at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>   at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
>   at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
>   at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
>   at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:774)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>   at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>   at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
> ```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Ok, sorted it. Just changed    <source>/resources/tags/menu.xhtml</source>    to     <source>../tags/menu.xhtml</source>    in my taglib file and it works. However, I'd like to know what i can use to reference my files other than relative paths. If anyone's got an answer I'll take it. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I sorted this out by changing the way I reference my tag file in my tag lib.

First I discovered the file that was causing problems using tomcat7 instead of glassfish which, for some reason, does not give the name of the file.

Then in pac-taglib.xhtml I changed :

> `<source>/resources/tags/menu.xhtml</source>`

with

> `<source>../tags/menu.xhtml</source>`

However, if someone knows how to reference the tags other than relative ref I'd be glad to know.
Thanks again to those took the time to search.
Any additional info are still welcome.